# How to sort object with ramda js

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering, ramda.js

I want to sort the following object,

```
const form = {
A_ALL: {A1_ALL: { A1_ONE: 'Y', A2_TWO: 'Y', A3_THREE: 'Y'}, A2: {A2_FOUR: 'Y', A2_FIVE: 'N', A2_SIX: 'Y'}, A3: 'Y', A4: 'N'},
B_ALL: {B1_ALL: { B1_ONE: 'Y', B1_TWO: 'Y', B1_THREE: 'Y'}, B2: {B2_FOUR: 'Y', B2_FIVE: 'Y', B2_SIX: 'Y'}, B3: 'Y', B4: 'Y'},
C_ALL: {XX: 'Y', YY:'Y'},
D: 'Y',
E: 'N'
}
```

I am implementing a form with nested check boxes who's value can be 'Y' or 'N'. I want to capture only the 'Y' check boxes, and if all of the child check boxes are 'Y', I want to discard them and get only parent checkbox. Above is the object which has all the check box values. I want the object to be sorted to:

```
{
A_ALL: {A1_ALL: 'Y', A2: {A2_FOUR: 'Y', A2_SIX: 'Y'}, A3: 'Y'},
B_ALL : 'Y',
C: 'Y',
D: 'Y'
}
```

My code so far looks like this:

```
const FORM = ({ A1_ALL: { a: 'Y', b: 'Y', c: 'Y' }, B1_ALL: { a: 'Y', b: 'Y', c: 'N' }, C1_ALL: { a: 'Y', b: 'Y', c: 'Y' }, }) 
const eY = equals('Y') 
const isSelected = compose(all(eY), values) 
const groupValue = when(isSelected, always('Y')); 
const formValue = map(groupValue) formValue(FORM) Result is {A1_ALL: "Y", C1_ALL: "Y", B1_ALL: {a: "Y", b: "Y", c: "N"}}
```

Comment: I have the following code implemented using Ramda,                                                         const FORM = ({
  A1_ALL: { a: 'Y', b: 'Y', c: 'Y' },
  B1_ALL: { a: 'Y', b: 'Y', c: 'N' },
  C1_ALL: { a: 'Y', b: 'Y', c: 'Y' },
})
const eY = equals('Y')
const isSelected = compose(all(eY), values)
const groupValue = when(isSelected, always('Y'));
const formValue = map(groupValue)
formValue(FORM)                                                                                                            Result is {A1_ALL: "Y", C1_ALL: "Y", B1_ALL: {a: "Y", b: "Y", c: "N"}}

Comment: given that your result is an object that recursively contains all `Y`s, shouldn't the end result just be the string `Y`?

Answer (score 1):

You're close with your attempt, you just need to recursively call `map` for each object that it finds in the values of the object.

```js
const form = { A_ALL: {A1_ALL: { A1_ONE: 'Y', A2_TWO: 'Y', A3_THREE: 'Y'}, A2: {A2_FOUR: 'Y', A2_FIVE: 'N', A2_SIX: 'Y'}, A3: 'Y', A4: 'N'}, B_ALL: {B1_ALL: { B1_ONE: 'Y', B1_TWO: 'Y', B1_THREE: 'Y'}, B2: {B2_FOUR: 'Y', B2_FIVE: 'Y', B2_SIX: 'Y'}, B3: 'Y', B4: 'Y'}, C_ALL: {XX: 'Y', YY:'Y'}, D: 'Y', E: 'N' }

const eY = R.equals('Y') 
const isSelected = R.compose(R.all(eY), R.values) 
const groupValue = R.when(isSelected, R.always('Y'))

const fn = objOrString => R.pipe(
  R.unless(R.is(String), R.map(fn)),
  R.unless(R.is(String), groupValue),
  R.unless(R.is(String), R.filter(R.either(R.is(Object), R.equals('Y'))))
)(objOrString)

console.log(fn(form))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is a cleaner version of what I did.  But both are only partial solutions.  If you look at the expected output, any sub-object with only `'Y'` values should become just `'Y'`.

Comment: The example that I had was already collapsing the objects that only contained 'Y's into 'Y', using the functions that @smitach already had (`groupValue` and friends). I did, however, miss that all of the 'N's were being filtered out in the desired output. I've updated the answer now to also filter out the non-Y strings from sub-objects when they aren't only made up of 'Y' in the input.

Comment: Very nice!  I was just about to go back to figure this out.

Comment: Could the `objOrString` parameter and corresponding `(objOrString)` just be skipped?

Comment: Asad: If we were to remove the parameter, `fn` would still be undefined at the time `map(fn)` is evaluated. Having it declared as a function delays the evaluation of `map(fn)` until after `fn` has been defined.

Comment: How can do this - In case all the the all key values are Y, I want the result to be {A_ALL: 'Y', B_ALL: 'Y', C_ALL: 'Y', D: 'Y', E: 'Y'}. Currently I get "Y".

Comment: @smitach: If you want to keep the top-level keys, you can map over the object using the same `fn`. You will however also need to reject any top-level keys with a `N` value.

e.g. `topLevelFn = R.pipe(R.reject(R.equals('N')), R.map(fn)); topLevelFn(form)`

Answer (score 0):

I have a partial solution, and no time at the moment to take the next step.  It essentially filters out any values that are not `'Y'`s.  You should then be able to add another step to slim this down by recursively replacing values which are objects containing only `'Y'` values with just `'Y'`.

```js
const form = {
      A_ALL: {A1_ALL: { A1_ONE: 'Y', A2_TWO: 'Y', A3_THREE: 'Y'}, A2: {A2_FOUR: 'Y', A2_FIVE: 'N', A2_SIX: 'Y'}, A3: 'Y', A4: 'N'},
      B_ALL: {B1_ALL: { B1_ONE: 'Y', B1_TWO: 'Y', B1_THREE: 'Y'}, B2: {B2_FOUR: 'Y', B2_FIVE: 'Y', B2_SIX: 'Y'}, B3: 'Y', B4: 'Y'},
      C_ALL: {XX: 'Y', YY:'Y'},
      D: 'Y',
      E: 'N'
}

const isObject = s => Object.prototype.toString.call(s) == '[object Object]'
const isArray = s => Object.prototype.toString.call(s) == '[object Array]'

const collect = pairs => pairs.reduce(
  (a, [k, v]) => ({...a, [k]: isArray(v) ? collect(v) : v}),
  {}
)

const spread = val => obj => Object.entries(obj)
  .filter(([k, v]) => v == val || isObject(v))
  .map(([k, v]) => isObject(v) ? [k, spread(val)(v)] : [k, v])

const findMatchingKeys = (val, obj) => collect(spread(val)(obj))

console.log(findMatchingKeys('Y', form))
```

This solution doesn't use Ramda.  I'm one of the founders of Ramda, and a big fan of the library, but I don't see Ramda offering much help here, only a few minor clean-ups.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different approach that (afaict) produces the same result as Scott Christopher's answer:

```js
// Ramda doesn't support folding objects, so we have to define this here
// :: Monoid m -> (a -> m) -> StrMap a -> m
const foldMap = M => f => o =>
  R.keys(o).reduce((p, c) => M.append(p)(f(o[c])), M.empty);

// :: Monoid Boolean
const And = { empty: true, append: x => y => x && y };

// Each layer of the form can be thought of as a string map, where
// a key is mapped to one of the strings "Y" or "N", or to a value
// of some given type `a`
// :: type ValueOr a = "Y" | "N" | a
// :: type FormLayer a = StrMap (ValueOr a)

// We can think of a form as an infinite nesting of form layers
// :: type Fix f = f (Fix f)
// :: type Form = Fix FormLayer
//              = FormLayer (FormLayer (FormLayer (FormLayer ...)))

// Recursion schemes can help us promote a function for operating
// on one layer of the structure to a function that operates on an
// infinite nesting of layers
// :: Functor f -> (f a -> a) -> Fix f -> a
const cata = F => alg => {
  const rec = x => alg(F.map(rec)(x));
  return rec;
};

// It's useful to factor repeated case analysis into a pattern
const ValOr = {
  Y: "Y",
  N: "N",
  Other: x => x,
  match: ({ Y, N, Other }) => v => v === "Y" ? Y : v === "N" ? N : Other(v),
  map: f => ValOr.match({ Y, N, Other: f })
};
const { Y, N, Other } = ValOr;

// :: Functor FormLayer
const FormLayer = { map: f => R.map(ValOr.map(f)) };

// :: ValueOr _ -> Boolean
const isY = ValOr.match({ Y: true, N: false, Other: _ => false });
// :: FormLayer _ -> Boolean
const allYs = foldMap(And)(isY);
// :: Form -> ValueOr Form
const squashYs = cata(FormLayer)(o => allYs(o) ? Y : Other(o));

// :: ValueOr _ -> Boolean
const isntN = ValOr.match({ Y: true, N: false, Other: _ => true });
// :: Form -> Form
const filterNs = cata(FormLayer)(R.filter(isntN));

// :: Form -> ValueOr Form
const f = R.pipe(
  // Squash Y-only objects recursively
  squashYs,
  // If the top level result is still a form, filter out the "N"s recursively
  ValOr.match({ Y, N, Other: filterNs })
);

// :: Form
const form = {
  A_ALL: {
    A1_ALL: { A1_ONE: "Y", A2_TWO: "Y", A3_THREE: "Y" },
    A2: { A2_FOUR: "Y", A2_FIVE: "N", A2_SIX: "Y" },
    A3: "Y",
    A4: "N"
  },
  B_ALL: {
    B1_ALL: { B1_ONE: "Y", B1_TWO: "Y", B1_THREE: "Y" },
    B2: { B2_FOUR: "Y", B2_FIVE: "Y", B2_SIX: "Y" },
    B3: "Y",
    B4: "Y"
  },
  C_ALL: { XX: "Y", YY: "Y" },
  D: "Y",
  E: "N"
};

// :: ValueOr Form
const result = f(form);

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```